# Specifying coordinates with \def in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, tex-core

I'm starting with PSTricks. I use the following macro to set cartesian coordinates:

```
\def\newPoint#1(#2,#3)
{
    \expandafter\def\csname x#1\endcsname{#2}
    \expandafter\def\csname y#1\endcsname{#3}
    \expandafter\def\csname ponto#1\endcsname{#1(#2,#3)}
    \expandafter\def\csname p#1\endcsname{#2,#3}
}
```

As you can see, these coordinates define internally new control sequences.

An example of use:

```
\newPoint A(-6,3)
\newPoint B(4,4)
\psline(\pA)(\pB) %or
%\psline(\xA,\yA)(\xB,\yB)
```

This approach is convenient, because it makes the code cleaner.

I will show another example:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-3.5,-1)(1,3)
        \newPoint A(-2,2.5) \uput[ul](\pA){$ A $}
        \newPoint B(-0.5,2.5) \uput[ur](\pB){$ B $}
        \newPoint C(0.5,1) \uput[r](\pC){$ C $}
        \newPoint D(-0.5,-0.5) \uput[dr](\pD){$ D $}
        \newPoint E(-2,-0.5) \uput[dl](\pE){$ E $}
        \newPoint F(-3,1) \uput[l](\pF){$ F $}

        \pspolygon[showpoints=true]%
        (\pA)(\pB)(\pC)(\pD)(\pE)(\pF)%

        \psset{linestyle=dashed, dash=3pt 2pt, linewidth=.6pt}
        \psline(\pA)(\pE)
        \psline(\pA)(\pD)
        \psline(\pA)(\pC)
        \psline(\pF)(\pB)
        \psline(\pF)(\pC)
        \psline(\pF)(\pD)
        \psline(\pE)(\pC)
        \psline(\pE)(\pB)
        \psline(\pD)(\pB)

        \psdot(-1.25,1)
    \end{pspicture}
    \caption{An hexagon}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Hexagon generated with PSTricks]

I would like to improve this process by eliminating the need to enter the parentheses. For example, wish I could type:

```
\pspolygon[showpoints=true]%
        \pA\pB\pC\pD\pE\pF%
```

instead of

```
\pspolygon[showpoints=true]%
        (\pA)(\pB)(\pC)(\pD)(\pE)(\pF)%
```

Is this possible? There is a way to improve this macro?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! All the functionalities you describe, except eliminating the parentheses already exist, either in `pst-node`or in `pst-eucl`, even with a simpler syntax. Ther also exist the `pst-poly` to easily draw regular polygons, with any number of sides, convex or not.

Comment: The use of delimiters like `(..)` provides a means to identify a next parameter. If you wish to drop this in favour of a simpler notation, it may not be possible to distinguish between a proper parameter and/or just another token. The only way around it may be to supply an "ending token", like `\relax`, say: `\pspolygon[..]\pA\pB...\pF\relax`

Comment: The \relax control sequence don't work for me... Even so, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\makeatletter
\def\newPoint{\@ifnextchar[\newPoint@i{\newPoint@i[l]}}
\def\newPoint@i[#1]#2(#3){\pnode(#3){#2}\uput[#1](#3){$#2$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-1)(1,3)
    \newPoint[ul]A(-2,2.5)
    \newPoint[ur]B(-0.5,2.5)
    \newPoint[r] C(0.5,1)
    \newPoint[dr]D(-0.5,-0.5)
    \newPoint[dl]E(-2,-0.5)
    \newPoint    F(-3,1)

    \pspolygon[showpoints](A)(B)(C)(D)(E)(F)
    \psset{linestyle=dashed, dash=3pt 2pt, linewidth=.6pt}
    \psline(A)(E)(C)(A)(D)(B)(F)(D)
    \psline(F)(C)\psline(E)(B)
    \psdot(-1.25,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

A definition of `\newPoints[..]...(..,..)[...]...(...)` may also be possible

Comment: Thank you very much. This did not eliminate the use of parentheses, but its solution greatly simplifies the code.